# SQLite is not creating database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to create nd insert database in the project for this i use sqlite but onCreate() method is not working. How can I fix the error? 
Thanks.

**Error:**

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tablehomepage": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create tablehomepage(idinteger primary key AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT );

**Code**

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="database";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSİON=1;
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE="homepage";
    public static final String ROW_ID="id";
    public static final String ROW_TITLE="title";


    public Database(Context context) {

        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSİON);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table" + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
                + Database.ROW_ID + "integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + Database.ROW_TITLE + " TEXT );");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXİSTS "+ DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addData(String title){

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(ROW_TITLE,title.trim());
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,cv);
        db.close();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing several spaces in your Query of Creating table. you need to add spaces between keyword. Like TABLE, Integer etc...

use this:

```
 db.execSQL("create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
            + Database.ROW_ID + " integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + Database.ROW_TITLE + " TEXT );");
```